# How to deal with multiple choices based on value (enum) using strategy or functional interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, enums, functional-programming

I am dealing with a case when I have an `enum`:

```
public enum CurrencyType {
    BTC, ETH
}
```

A pojo:

```
public class Challenge {
    private final String walletAddress;
    private final CurrencyType currencyType;
    //getters, constructors, setters
}
```

A service:

```
@Service
public ChallengeService {
   public Challenge verifyMessage(final Challenge challenge) {
           Challenge verifiedChallenge;
       switch (challenge.getCurrencyType()) {
           case BTC:
               verifiedChallenge = verifyBTCMessage(challenge);
               break;
           case ETH:
               verifiedChallenge = verifyETHMessage(challenge);
               break;
           default:
               throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + challenge.getCurrencyType());
       }
    return verifiedChallenge;
    }

    private Challenge verifyBTCMessage(Challenge challenge) { //implementation here }

    private Challenge verifyETHMessage(Challenge challenge) { //implementation here }

}
```

Currently the enum contains only 2 values, `ETH` and `BTC`, but some day the number of values in this enum can grow to 5, 10 or even more.

At this point I am thinking that my approach is wrong. I was looking at Strategy pattern, it looks nice, but it seems that at some point I won't be able to escape the whole *ifology* (or *switchology* to be exact here) to delegate the `Challenge` object to adequate methods based on the `CurrencyType` enum value.

While reading about strategy pattern on refactoring guru, I have found this information (in the section of *cons* of the strategy pattern)

```
A lot of modern programming languages have functional type support that lets you implement different versions of an algorithm inside a set of anonymous functions.
```

This seems that this could be a better approach, but... I am in a beginner phase of learning functional programming, and to be completely honest - I don't know where to start. Or maybe the strategy pattern would be sufficient but I am missing some crucial thing about it? All I want to achieve is to get rid of the *switchology* if possible.

Comment: Why don't you add the `verify` method to the enum?

Comment: I will not recommend the above approach as this will lead to an unmaintained and huge code in CurrencyType enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create an interface as follows:

```java
public interface MessageVerifier {
     public CurrencyType handles();
     public Challenge verifyMessage(Challenge challenge);
}
```

Then for BTC you would have something like (you will have one implementation for each CurrencyType):

```java
@Component
public class BtcMessageVerifier implements MessageVerifier {
     public CurrencyType handles() {
         return CurrencyType.BTC;
     }

     public Challenge verifyMessage(Challenge challenge) {
         // Your logic here
     }
}
```

You can now inject the list of all `MessageVerifier`s in `ChallengeService` and rearrange it into a Map so that it is easier to use when needed.

```java
@Service
public ChallengeService {
   
   private Map<CurrencyType, MessageVerifier> messageVerifierPerCurrency;

   @Autowired
   public ChallengeService(List<MessageVerifier> messageVerifiers) {
        this.messageVerifierPerCurrency = messageVerifiers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MessageVerifier::handles, Function.identity()));
   }  

   public Challenge verifyMessage(final Challenge challenge) {
       Challenge verifiedChallenge;
       if (messageVerifierPerCurrency.containsKey(challenge.getCurrencyType())) {
          verifiedChallenge = messageVerifierPerCurrency.get(challenge.getCurrencyType()).verifyMessage(challenge);
       } else
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + challenge.getCurrencyType());
       }
       return verifiedChallenge;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! But I am an constructor injection fan, can this list of verifiers be injected through constructor?

Comment: Yes it can. And I actually prefer constructor injection and in this case, it makes it even simpler because you can drop the `@PostConstruct` method. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Have you tried it and make it work or do you still have any questions?

Comment: I think that's all for it ;) I have combined both answers and added bits from myself, and it is working perfectly ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this could be implemented as follows:

```
interface Verifier {
     boolean isMatched(CurrencyType type);
     CurrencyType currency();
     Challenge verify(Challenge challenge);
}
```

And each concrete class will be used/matched for a particular currency.

Comment: So we are talking here about creating multiple services, and every service is implementing this verifier and is validating one `CurrencyType`? I'm asking because I am trying to understand how to implement it this way.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And in the ChallengeService you can create a Map< CurrencyType , Verifier> in constructor using Verifier.currency() method ( I have edited my original post) 
Also this will resolve thousands line of codes  issue when adding CurrencyType.verify()  method as proposed above.

Comment: My brain froze here a bit. So `CurrencyType currency();` should return the `CurrencyType` for given verifier implementation as I presume, `isMatched` should compare given `CurrencyType` with what `currency()` returns, `verify()` should contain all the verification logic, that's easy, but I don't get this `Map<CurrencyType, Verifier>` thing, and what `Verifier.currency()` has to do with it... Should this Map of currencies and verified autowired somehow? I'm lost here...

Comment: Here it is 

@Service
public class ChallengeService {
   private final Map<CurrencyType, Verifier> vMap;

  public ChallengeService(List<Verifier> verifiers) {
    vMap = verifiers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Verifier::currency, Function.identity());
  }

  public Challenge verifyMessage(final Challenge challenge) {
            Verifier verifier = vMap.get(challenge. getCurrencyType());
            if(verifier == null) {
               throw new IllegalStateException("...");
          }
           return verifier.verify(verifiedChallenge);
    }
}

Comment: could You explain a bit what is `Function.identity()` doing exactly? Information from Javadoc `Returns a function that always returns its input argument.` isn't clear enough for me...

Comment: Oh, I think I get the *general* idea, instead of writing ie. `verifier -> verifier` I am just using `Function.identity()`, am I right?

Comment: yes, you are right!